# Fastest way to export keys from cassandra

Tags: java, cassandra

What is the fastest way to export all the rowkeys from a column family in cassandra (0.7.x and later versions) with Java APIs or other tools ?

Currently I am using the Java Pelops API, and paging through all records, but Im wondering if there is a better mechanism.

I am specifically interested in only exporting the rowkeys (no columns/subcolumns), so Im wondering if there is a section of the cassandra direct storage APIs that could be used to do this as quickly as possible (bypassing thrift).

Answer (score 1):

What about using Java [hector](/questions/tagged/hector) client. Sample taken from
https://github.com/rantav/hector/wiki/User-Guide

```
RangeSlicesQuery<String, String, String> rangeSlicesQuery = 
HFactory.createRangeSlicesQuery(keyspace, stringSerializer, 
     stringSerializer, stringSerializer);
rangeSlicesQuery.setColumnFamily("Standard1");
rangeSlicesQuery.setKeys("fake_key_", "");
rangeSlicesQuery.setReturnKeysOnly(); // use this
rangeSlicesQuery.setRowCount(5);
Result<OrderedRows<String, String, String>> result = rangeSlicesQuery.execute();
```

- [thrift](/questions/tagged/thrift) is API interface for [cassandra](/questions/tagged/cassandra). Going directly to storage would require you to read data files in binary. Code above should give you good performance.
- If you need this for one time export then I would say it's OK. If you need this for production you should reconsider your data-model - you may be doing something wrong.
- You may need to split the query using multiple key ranges in case you need to scan many rows.